# Products is not displaying in category page in Magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento, magento2

After re-index process, products are not displaying in category page.I try many possibility to solve this but not get solution.

Comment: how did you create products and assign to categories?

Comment: I done migration process from Magento1.8.0. to Magento2.2.0. After that i do reindex and clear cache. After that i see product is not displayed in category page.

Comment: Have you any solution to this problem? **@Muk**

Comment: No, May be following may help https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/After-Migration-Products-not-showing-on-Frontend/td-p/42005

Comment: Thanks, but this is not worked for me.

Comment: I check all data and also check that product are assigned to a category, no missing data is available. Can you think about it that why products are not displayed on the category page? **@muk**

Comment: You may check stock, visibility also

Comment: I also check stock, visibility but not display product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem. Magento didn't get placeholder image.

I see that in **/pub/media/catalog/product/**, no path define for placeholder image. that's why the product is not displayed in category page in my case.

I put an image in **/pub/media/catalog/product/images/placeholder/image.jpg**

This is work for me properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check any modules you have installed. We experienced the same issue after upgrading to 2.2.2. After a lot of investigation, we found the issue was with Magestore Inventory Management. Disabling the module restored normal Magento behaviour.

Recommend you disable additional modules, starting with those that may impact products/categories (*module:disable*). Then *setup:upgrade*, *setup:di:compile*, *indexer:reindex*, *cache:clean* and see if listings are restored.

If after disabling a module the issue is resolved, re-enable it and see if it comes back (*module:enable* followed by the other commands).